# Can I use || instead of else if in C?

Tags: c

I'm new to C, and I'm trying to improve a program's source code that I found in a book. I noticed that the source code contains a lot of "else if" conditions but has the same results, so I tried to compress them into a smaller code using || operator in the if function.
1st code:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
int main(){
    char card_name[3];
    puts("Enter the card_name: ");
    scanf("%2s", card_name);
    int val = 0;
    if (card_name[0] == 'K'){
        val = 10;
    } else if (card_name[0] == 'Q'){
        val = 10;
    } else if (card_name[0] == 'J'){
        val = 10;
    } else if (card_name[0] == 'A'){
        val = 11;
    } else {
        val = atoi(card_name);
    }
    printf("The card name value is %i\n", val);
    return 0;
}
```

My improvement:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
int main(){
    char card_name[3];
    puts("Enter the card_name: ");
    scanf("%2s", card_name);
    int val = 0;
    if (card_name[0] == 'K' || 'Q' || 'J' ){
        val = 10;
    } else if (card_name[0] == 'A'){
        val = 11;
    } else {
        val = atoi(card_name);
    }
    printf("The card name value is %i\n", val);
    return 0;
}
```

The problem with mine: When I write any another value it always prompt 10. What should I do ?

Comment: `||` separates conditions, not values. You need to write `card_name[0] == 'K' || card_name[0] == 'Q' || card_name[0] == 'J'`. Otherwise, just `'Q'` or `'J'` will be treated as a condition, as if you wrote `else if ('Q')`, which takes the character's ASCII code and checks if it is non-zero (which is always true).

Comment: Learn what the expression `(card_name[0] == 'K' || 'Q' || 'J' )` *really* means to the compiler, as it clearly isn't what you think. Hint: That always evaluates to true.

Comment: Thank you all guys. That works. @WhozCraig Why is that? Why it's always evaluates to true ?

Comment: @SeanBright That worked good as well. But the compiler returns an error:cards.c: In function 'main':
cards.c:8:9: warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function 'strchr' [enabled by default]
     if (strchr("JQK", card_name[0])){
         ^

Comment: @AmineMarzouki there are a half-dozen answers below that divulge the reason why the expression is always true.

Comment: @SeanBright Even if I added it, the error still exist.

Comment: @WhozCraig I didn't understand it well. I tried to change the value to '0' and 0 so as C intercepts it wrong, but nothing happend.

Comment: @SeanBright I will. Thanks though :)

Comment: @SeanBright  mates, I really didn't understand why the author choose to put 3 items in the card name array and scan for 2 in scanf function. I changed both of the values to 1. And everything seems to work just fine. Could you clarify please

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue is in `C` anything that is not `0` is a truthy value so in your code you have `if (card_name[0] == 'K' || 'Q' || 'J')`. This checks if `card_name[0] == 'K'` but this will always evaluate to true because you have `|| 'Q'` and `C` treats `'Q'` as truth. Here is the proper fix

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
int main(){
    char card_name[3];
    puts("Enter the card_name: ");
    scanf("%2s", card_name);
    int val = 0;
    if (card_name[0] == 'K' || card_name[0] == 'Q' || card_name[0] == 'J' ){
        val = 10;
    } else if (card_name[0] == 'A'){
        val = 11;
    } else {
        val = atoi(card_name);
    }
    printf("The card name value is %i\n", val);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: another question please. Why we declared 3 items in the card name array while we're using just one char ?

Comment: Detail: "anything that _does not compare_ to 0 is a truthy value".  `-0.0` differs from `0`, yet `if(-0.0)` is not truthy.  Other examples include null pointers which are not `0`.

Comment: @chux true! I was more in the whole `int`, `char`, `short`, `long`, `byte`, universe that `0` is false. If you are using `double`or `float` `0.0` is also false.

Comment: @AmineMarzouki we're not declaring 3 items in the array, we are checking the value at index `0` against 3 chars.

Answer (score 1):

This is not the correct expression:

```
(card_name[0] == 'K' || 'Q' || 'J' )
```

This will be always evaluate to true because 'Q' and 'J' are not `0`.

You should write:

```
(card_name[0] == 'K') || (card_name == 'Q')  || (card_name == 'J')
```

Answer (score 1):

```
if (card_name[0] == 'K' || 'Q' || 'J' ){
    val = 10;
}
```

`'Q'`, etc is evaluated as a truth statement and since the value of the char is not 0 will always be `true`

should be

```
if (card_name[0] == 'K' || card_name[0] == 'Q' || card_name[0] == 'J' ){
    val = 10;
}
```

Comment: @Amine, the array `card_name` is declared as a `char` array with 3 slots because a card name is most likely A-K which means a card name could be 10. If a card name is 10, the array would look like this `card_name` = `|1|0|\000|`, with `card_name[0]` = `1`, `card_name[1]` = `0`, and `card_name[2]` = `\000`, the null-terminator. The `char` array size in C always has to be one greater than the amount of `char`s you have because C needs a way to know that you have reached the end of an array and it doesn't keep reading into some other memory that is not the array.

Answer (score 0):

`if (card_name[0] == 'K' || 'Q' || 'J' )`

should be

`if (card_name[0] == 'K' || card_name[0] == 'Q' || card_name[0] == 'J' )`

`'Q'` will always evaluate to true, you need the full comparison in each or.

Answer (score 0):

Check the operator precedence in you if statement. If you look here **http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence**, you can see, that == has higher priority than ||.

The correct if statement should be like this:

```
if (card_name[0] == 'K' || card_name[0] == 'Q' || card_name[0] == 'J' ){
```

If you are not sure, what is the operator precedence, you can use brackets like this:

```
if ((card_name[0] == 'K') || (card_name[0] == 'Q') || (card_name[0] == 'J') ){
```

Note:
Your code is not correct, because `if(card_name[0] == 'K' || 'Q' || 'J' )` is understood as `if(card_name[0] == 'K' || true || true)` which is always true

Answer (score 0):

No, as many others have pointed out, using `if (card_name[0] == 'K' || 'Q' || 'J' )` is wrong, and they have also described why and how to correct it.  However, if you really just want a shorter and snappier way of writing the test, you could go for a `switch`-statement:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    char card_name[3];
    puts("Enter the card_name: ");
    scanf("%2s", card_name);
    int val = 0;

    switch (card_name[0]) {
    case 'K': /* fallthrough */
    case 'Q': /* fallthrough */
    case 'J': val = 10; break;
    case 'A': val = 11; break;
    default:  val = atoi(card_name);
    }

    printf("The card name value is %i\n", val);
    return 0;
}
```

Note that a `switch` statement is *not* a generic replacement for `if`-`else if` in C as each `case` needs to be constant integer expression (expressing it sloppily, a C book will tell you the restrictions correctly).

Answer (score -1):

Always keep in mind `||`means one of the condition must be true to proceed . if `&&` is used , it checks all the condition and proceeds only if all the conditions satisfy. Pretty basic info for noobies...

Comment: I know !. That was NOT the problem.